# Обучение PyQt4, какие есть основные функции Qt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt4

Обучение программированию без какой либо документации практически невозможно. Я только начинаю изучать язык и без подробного описания, это дается трудновато.
Есть ли подробное описание функций для Qt4 на русском языке и примеры с ними?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Материала по сабжу полно. Есть даже небеизвестная [бумажная книга](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4005805/) на русском и ещё кое какие [неизвестные](http://www.ozon.ru/?context=search&group=12256&text=qt+4).

[Документация по Qt4](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/) вполне исчерпывающая. Примеров на любую тему хватает, стоит только написать "qt4 youusubject example" в Google и получить свой пример.

**UPD** Для питона есть [PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt). С этой страницы есть ссылки на множество ресурсов по теме.

Answer (score 4):

`шаг 1: А.Сузи - язык программирования python
шаг 2: Boudewijn Rempt - GUI Programming with Python QT Edition [2001].chm
шаг 3: google.ru - pyqt4 class reference
шаг 4: http://nullege.com/codes/search/PyQt4
шаг 5: google.ru
все очень просто`